# In Minkowski spacetime diagrams, how is the formula $\tan(θ) = v/c$ for the angle between $ct$ and $ct'$ derived?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, coordinate-systems, inertial-frames

In Minkowski spacetime diagrams, how is the formula $\tan(θ) = v/c$ for the angle between $ct$ and $ct'$ derived?

Comment: You're going to need to give us some more information. The quantities $ct$ and $ct'$ are numbers, not geometrical objects. Do you mean the axes? And there is no standard way of talking an angle in this context. It sounds like you're looking at someone's specific way of presenting something, but it seems nonstandard, so other people aren't going to understand what you mean without more information.

Comment: @Ben This is a relatively standard formula, useful for drawing spacetime diagrams. $\theta$ is the Euclidean angle between the t and t' axes, assuming one of them is vertical.

Comment: Distance = rate x time.

Comment: Where does that formula come from? Can you include a reference? Thanks!

Comment: $tan^{-1}(v/c)$ has its uses, but even more useful is the [rapidity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rapidity), $tanh^{-1}(v/c)$, because it's additive. In early works on SR, Einstein calls the hyperbolic tangent the imaginary tangent.

Answer (score 3):

One way to derive this result, almost certainly not the neatest, is to use the Lorentz transform$$x'=\gamma \left(x-vt\right).$$
The $ct'$ axis is defined by $x'$ being zero all the way along it, so on the Minkowski diagram it is the line$$x=vt\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \text{that is} \ \ \ \ \ \ \ x=\frac{v}{c}ct.$$
So the gradient of this line when *ct* is plotted horizontally and *x* vertically is$$\tan \theta = \frac{v}{c}.$$
If we plot $ct$ vertically and *x* horizontally, the angle, $\theta\ $, between the *ct* axis and the *ct'* axis won't change!

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to be sure exactly what you're confused about, but you appear to be overthinking this.  An inertial particle's velocity (relative to you) is **defined** as the tangent of the angle between its worldline and yours in relativity just as it is in classical mechanics.